# View the results of Behat tests in the browser like Jasmine

Tags: php, behat

So Jasmine has a page that runs the js tests and shows the results.

[image]

Is there anything similar for Behat, that runs the tests and shows the results.

Basically I want a non tech to be able to visit a page to see if the project is hitting the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behat 2.x has [an html formatter](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html). You can use it to generate an html page and publish it somewhere, so others could see the results.

Behat 3 doesn't have a built in html formatter just yet (see https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/359). However, there's a third party extension - [emuse/behat-html-formatter](https://github.com/dutchiexl/BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin). It not only allows you to generate the classic Behat 2 style report, but has an additional one.

[image: Twig report]

[image: Classic report]

Comment: That's great thanks. Another case of not knowing what words to google for - 'output formatters'!